# java.net.DatagramSocket Bind error

Tags: java, c, scala

I'm experimenting with some client server code where the server is a C program on a Linux VM and the client is a scala application on the Host Mac OSX.

The client run on my host machine ( MacOs X ) 
which just does this

```
val ia = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.1.5")
val socket = new DatagramSocket( 9345, ia )
```

Every time I run the above, the creation of the DatagramSocket fails with

> Can't assign requested address

(I haven't got past that little snippet yet but basically its just a basic echo client-server)

I'm running a little server snippet written in C on a linux Virtual Machine. Its just a simple echo server.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sock, length, n;
   socklen_t fromlen;
   struct sockaddr_in server;
   struct sockaddr_in from;
   char buf[1024];

   if (argc < 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no port provided\n");
      exit(0);
   }

   sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if (sock < 0) error("Opening socket");
   length = sizeof(server);
   memset(&server, 0, length);
   server.sin_family=AF_INET;
   server.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
   server.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));
   if (bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,length)<0) 
       error("binding");
   fromlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
   while (1) {
       n = recvfrom(sock,buf,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fromlen);
       if (n < 0) error("recvfrom");
       write(1,"Received a datagram: ",21);
       write(1,buf,n);
       n = sendto(sock,"Got your message\n",17,
                  0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,fromlen);
       if (n  < 0) error("sendto");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I run the above server with

```
a.out 9345 // a.out exec name, 9345 -port number
```

I checked to make sure the port number wasn't being used. When I run a simple client on the host machine written in C, I have no problem reaching out to the echo server. Here is the C client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void error(const char *);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sock, n;
   unsigned int length;
   struct sockaddr_in server, from;
   struct hostent *hp;
   char buffer[256];

   if (argc != 3) { printf("Usage: server port\n");
                    exit(1);
   }
   sock= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if (sock < 0) error("socket");

   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
   if (hp==0) error("Unknown host");

   bcopy((char *)hp->h_addr, 
        (char *)&server.sin_addr,
         hp->h_length);
   server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
   length=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
   printf("Please enter the message: ");
   bzero(buffer,256);
   fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
   n=sendto(sock,buffer,
            strlen(buffer),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&server,length);
   if (n < 0) error("Sendto");
   n = recvfrom(sock,buffer,256,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from, &length);
   if (n < 0) error("recvfrom");
   write(1,"Got an ack: ",12);
   write(1,buffer,n);
   close(sock);
   return 0;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help on this. Is there some Mac or linux based security that reject network connections coming from the JVM ?

Answer (score 0):

Is 10.0.1.5 one of your computer's addresses?

Comment: Yes it is... 10.0.1.5 is the address of the linux VM running the server. 10.0.1.6 is the address of the Mac OSX host machine. I ran a client based on the above java snipett and the C client mentioned above. The C client worked but the java client fails to bind to the socket.